# Group acting on set and stablizer

Tags: group-theory

I have the following question

assume $X$ is a set and $x,y \in X$ and that there is $g \in G$ such that $g*x=y$ .
I need to prove that $stb(y) = g \cdot stb(x) \cdot g^-1$

where

$ stb(x) = \{g \in G | g*x = x \}$

I need some help with getting started, thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll write $G_x$ for the stabilizer of $x$.

If $h \in G_y$ then $hgx = hy = y = gx$, so $g^{-1}hg \in G_x$. Hence $h = g(g^{-1}hg)g^{-1} \in gG_xg^{-1}$.

Conversely, if $h \in gG_xg^{-1}$ then $h = gh'g^{-1}$ for some $h'$ with $h'x = x$. Then $hy = hgx = (gh'g^{-1})gx = gh'x = gx = y$, so $h \in G_y$.

Answer (score 1):

$stb(y)=\{h \in G | h*y=y\}$

$stb(y)=\{h \in G | h*(g*x)=g*x\}$

$stb(y)=\{h \in G | g^{-1}*(h*(g*x))=g^{-1}*(g*x)\}$

$stb(y)=\{h \in G | g^{-1}hg*x=x\}$

$stb(y)=\{h \in G | g^{-1}hg \in stb(x)\}$

$stb(y)=\{h \in G | h \in g .stb(x) g^{-1}\}$

$stb(y)= g.stb(x).g^{-1}$

Comment: Thank you, can you explain the transition from the 3rd row to the 4th?

Comment: sorry it was a mistake, i corrected it

Answer (score 0):

If $h \in Stab(x)$, you get $ghg^{-1}y = ghx = gx = y$. Viceversa if $w \in Stab(y)$ you get $g^{-1}wgx = g^{-1}wy = g^{-1}y = x$.